# Until method doesn't throw timeoutException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get an element loaded with Ajax. This is my script:

```
..
WebElement account= (new WebDriverWait(driver, 15))
    .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("account")
...
```

When the 15 secs was reached `TimeOutException` was not thrown and the execution did not stop nor jumped to next instruction. The Ajax element was loaded before 15sec , I could see it, and the web seemed fully loaded.

I waited 10minutes before stopping the execution :(

My environment is:

```
WIN7
Selenium 2.44
Firefox 35
TestNg
Eclipse Luna.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does switching to `Chrome` or `PhantomJS` make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is related to the existing compatibility issues between `selenium 2.44` and `Firefox 35`:

- [Firefox 35: Passing arguments to executeScript isn't working](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8390&q=2.44%20arguments&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary)
- [FirefoxDriver fails to execute async script with FireFox 35](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8398)

As a current workaround, *downgrade to Firefox 34.0.5 or switch to Chrome*.